# Tag proposal: "particle-choice"

Tags: discussion, tags

While browsing through the [particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles) tag, I noticed there were a lot of comparisons, and that some of the questions were tagged [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), so I thought I might propose to add a "particle-choice" tag, and to remove the [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) tag for differences between particles (but only if there isn't also an aspect of the question which is about the differences between words, and if the question isn't about the differences between words and particles. In such cases both "word-choice" and "particle-choice" would be used.)

These are the following questions which would probably be affected, which is a fairly large number.

As usual, vote up for agree and down for disagree.

> - に vs で: [Particles: に vs. で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60/particles-%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7), [に vs で again: 前に vs 後で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7-again-%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AB-vs-%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A7), [に and で revisited](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A7-revisited), [What's the difference between に and で when speaking of time of an action?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/685/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A7-when-speaking-of-time-of-an-action), [Why is 一緒に correct and 一緒で incorrect?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/why-is-%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%AB-correct-and-%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%A7-incorrect), [Combining に/で particles with 等など(or other “etc.” stand-ins)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/combining-%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%A7-particles-with-%E7%AD%89%E3%80%90%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E3%80%91or-other-etc-stand-ins)
> - に vs で vs から: [その中( に / で / から ) What is the correct choice of particles?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD-%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%A7-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-what-is-the-correct-choice-of-particles)
> - に vs へ: [Can't に always replace へ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/cant-%E3%81%AB-always-replace-%E3%81%B8), [When going somewhere, is there any difference between e (へ) and ni (に)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80/when-going-somewhere-is-there-any-difference-between-e-%E3%81%B8-and-ni-%E3%81%AB), [へ or に particle for 曲がる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/%E3%81%B8-or-%E3%81%AB-particle-for-%E6%9B%B2%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B)
> - に vs の: [When to use 他ほかの or 他ほかに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/when-to-use-%E4%BB%96%E3%80%90%E3%81%BB%E3%81%8B%E3%80%91%E3%81%AE-or-%E4%BB%96%E3%80%90%E3%81%BB%E3%81%8B%E3%80%91%E3%81%AB)
> - に vs を: [Is there a difference between に伴う and を伴う?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/is-there-a-difference-between-%E3%81%AB%E4%BC%B4%E3%81%86-and-%E3%82%92%E4%BC%B4%E3%81%86), [Use of に and を with 触れる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/use-of-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%82%92-with-%E8%A7%A6%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)
> - に vs と:  [versus +と versus +に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/adv-versus-adv%E3%81%A8-versus-adv%E3%81%AB)
> - に vs と vs が: [Which particle to use with 出会う : と, に or が?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/which-particle-to-use-with-%E5%87%BA%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%AB-or-%E3%81%8C)
> - に vs で vs にて: [In this location context how are に, で and にて different?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/in-this-location-context-how-are-%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%A7-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6-different)
> - に vs が: [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%81%AB-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning)
> - にしては vs としては: [～にしては vs. ～としては](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/762/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-vs-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF)
> - に vs へ vs まで vs の方: [How to use へ (-e), に (-ni), まで (made) and の方 (no-hō) with destination and direction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-to-use-%E3%81%B8-e-%E3%81%AB-ni-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7-made-and-%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9-no-h%C5%8D-with-destination-and-direct)
> - に vs へ vs で: [Differences in meaning of using へ, に, or で in marking locations.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2164/differences-in-meaning-of-using-%E3%81%B8-%E3%81%AB-or-%E3%81%A7-in-marking-locations)
> - の vs が: [の versus が used to mark the subject of an appositive clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/%E3%81%AE-versus-%E3%81%8C-used-to-mark-the-subject-of-an-appositive-clause)
> - の vs は vs が: [How do I say “I am the best” ? の,は or が and 私 or 俺?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/how-do-i-say-i-am-the-best-%E3%81%AE-%E3%81%AF-or-%E3%81%8C-and-%E7%A7%81-or-%E4%BF%BA)
> - のは vs は: [What is the difference between は and のは?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AF-and-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF)
> - を vs が: [Why is it 日本語がわかります instead of 日本語をわかります?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/why-is-it-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-instead-of-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), [Logic behind “が” preferrence when using a “-たい” form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4278/logic-behind-%E3%81%8C-preferrence-when-using-a-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-form), [Is it true that all nouns must be able to accept a が particle and a を particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/is-it-true-that-all-nouns-must-be-able-to-accept-a-%E3%81%8C-particle-and-a-%E3%82%92-particle), [The difference between Aが見える and Bを見る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/the-difference-between-a%E3%81%8C%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-and-b%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B), [を vs が with use against 好き?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/%E3%82%92-vs-%E3%81%8C-with-use-against-%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D)
> - も+negative vs でも+positive: [The reason for using 何も+negative, but 何でも+positive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1565/the-reason-for-using-%E4%BD%95%E3%82%82negative-but-%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82positive)
> - は vs が: [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C/51#51), [Extracting from, and introducing to Universe of Discourse using は and が with こそあど-demonstratives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C/51#51)
> - で vs の: [Difference between で and の when referring to “usage”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/difference-between-%E3%81%A7-and-%E3%81%AE-when-referring-to-usage)
> - と vs を: [Can と and を be interchanged with 思う the way I think they can?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/can-%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%82%92-be-interchanged-with-%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86-the-way-i-think-they-can)
> - と vs て vs って: [と、て、って　Quoting Particle Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3913/%E3%81%A8%E3%80%81%E3%81%A6%E3%80%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%80%80quoting-particle-usage)
> - わ vs よ: [When women use わ at the end of a sentence, is it different from よ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/when-women-use-%E3%82%8F-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-is-it-different-from-%E3%82%88)
> - ね vs な: [What's the difference between ね and な as tag questions?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/343/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AD-and-%E3%81%AA-as-tag-questions)
> - じゃ vs では: [What is じゃ in じゃない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/what-is-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83-in-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
> - ほど vs ぐらい: [What is the difference between 「ほど」 {hodo} and 「ぐらい」 {gurai}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/408/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%80%8C%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9%E3%80%8D-hodo-and-%E3%80%8C%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%80%8D-gurai)
> - やら vs や: [Usage of ～やら～やら vs ～や～や](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%84%E3%82%89%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%84%E3%82%89-vs-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%84%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%84)
> - でより vs でのより: [How should I view でより and でのより?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/how-should-i-view-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A-and-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A)
> - ので vs　から: [When to use ～ので vs ～から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/when-to-use-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7-vs-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89)
> - とか vs など vs し: [How to say, “things like”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/how-to-say-things-like)
> - までに vs まで: [今までに vs. 今まで - what is the difference in meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/%E4%BB%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB-vs-%E4%BB%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7-what-is-the-difference-in-meaning)
> - many particles: [What is とは、のが、のは、には、 へは　and では？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/what-is-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%80%81%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81-%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AF%E3%80%80and-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%9F), [What are the various ways to express 'or' and when are they appropriate?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-are-the-various-ways-to-express-or-and-when-are-they-appropriate), [The many ways to say “and” in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/474/the-many-ways-to-say-and-in-japanese), [What are other language equivalents to Japanese particles?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-are-other-language-equivalents-to-japanese-particles)
> - particles (fairly general): [Particle confusion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/particle-confusion)

(Please note I only glanced through them, so I might've added some mistakenly. If you see any which have been, please add a comment or edit the list directly.)

Comment: At first, the idea sounded good to me, but as I looked through your list, I noticed some of them are not particles. I am concerned that these cases do not fit under "particle choice", and "word choice" will have more generality. But still, It makes sense to have a tag for choice among functional/closed class words.

Comment: @sawa if you see any which shouldn't be there, or you can think of a better way of classifying etc, feel free to edit. There are some there which I think should probably still retain "word-choice" even if this change were to take place as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many words, but not as many particles. It is more useful to just tag the question with the individual particle tags than a generic [particle-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-choice) one. Looking at [particle-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-choice) does not give us much more information about what the question is.

You may argue the same thing for [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) in the same line of thought as in "Then why doesn't each word get its own tag? Looking at [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) does not give us much more information about what the question is either". Well my reason is that there are just too many words to account for. And words are usually compared within a specific context, while particles are used in every sentence and deserve individual tags.

Comment: I'm not proposing that questions not be tagged with individual particle tags, it would be in addition. You could browse through e.g. [tag:particle-ni] to find differences between the ni particle and others, but I think there's a fair amount of noise, and it's not all in one place. But either way I'm finding this list itself pretty useful, so I'm happy whether the proposal succeeds or not I guess :D

Comment: I disagree because I think that choosing the right particle is the most difficult part of mastering grammar. Sometimes I swear that "ni" and "de" change meaning depending on the weather patterns on Mars...Also, as you can see by the list, we already have a pretty good number of questions, I don't think it would go unappreciated to have this tag.

Comment: My point is that if a question compares "ni" with "de", then it will invariably be tagged with "particle-ni" and "particle-de" anyway; it does not have much significance to add one more "particle-choice" to the already existing tags on the question. If I wanted to find a comparison between "ni" and "de" I would simply run a query using the two tags, including or disincluding "particle-choice" would not make the query more or less specific.

Comment: I think that if someone was having trouble specifically with choosing "ni" vs "de", browsing thru "particle-ni"/"de" would be OK I guess. The reason I proposed is that I think for people who're wondering in general "what's the difference between the particles?" and want to casually browse through (as I did) I think it'd be easier if there was a "particle-choice" (or similar) tag.